# How to construct a table (matrix) with two lists and arrays of data?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, pyomo

I want to create a matrix/table that I can later retrieve. The two dimensions are: Croptypes and FixedInputs.

```
Croptypes = ["barley", "rapeseed", "wheat"]
FixedInputs = ["land", "labor", "capital"]
Beta = [[0.3, 0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.3, 0.2, 0.2]]
```

The table/matrix should look like this:

```
          "barley"   "rapeseed"  "wheat" 
"land"      0.3        0.2         0.3
"labor"     0.1        0.1         0.1  
"capital"   0.3        0.2         0.2
```

But the length of the two lists (Croptypes and FixedInputs) may change later, so I want to have a function that can create this table and does not need to be adjusted even if I change the length of the two lists.

In pyomo there is a function called tabular_writer(), is this the write function to use?  if yes, can someone show me how?

or any other solutions?

Comment: Have you tried anything with pandas?

Comment: Try this `pd.DataFrame(data=Beta, index=FixedInputs, columns=Croptypes)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas Data frame creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562479/python-pandas-data-frame-creation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(Beta, FixedInputs, Croptypes))
```

Comment: it works! How can I convert the same matrix into a dictionary? The dictionary should look like this: dict = {(barley, land): 0.3, (barley, labor): 0.1, ...(wheat, capital):0.2}