# Convert dictionary to pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary below:
[{a:1, b:2}{a:4,c:2}]

for the above dictionary, I want to change to pandas dataframe below:

```
a b c
1 2 -
4 - 2
```

Can someone help how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Data frame creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562479/python-pandas-data-frame-creation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Refer this, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([{'a':1, 'b':2},{'a':4,'c':2}]).fillna('-')`