# adding sql query in for loop with multiple variable

Tags: python, sql, pandas, loops, for-loop

Is there a way to add SQL queries in a For Loop in python when i have two variable for each iteration?
i have two list, and each member of the list corresponds to another member of the list in the order in which they are in the list. Example:

```
list1 = ['727', '454', '565']

list2 = ['14','15','16']

my_query= '''
    select 
    my rows
    from my_table
    where field1 = var_from_list1 
    and field2 = var_from_list2
) '''
```

So there we have possible pairs for vars {'727', 14'}, {'454', '15'}, {'565','16'}
I want to make loop, which will take the variables from the list, insert them into the query, and then append results into pandas dataframe. I tried several options, but they did not work for me. I suppose that first need to create a dataframe with the necessary fields, and then append loop results into it, but idk how to correctly transfer the variables inside the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your real query around them, and then execute:

```
list1 = ['727', '454', '565']
list2 = ['14', '15', '16']

for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2):
    print("select my_rows from my_table where field1=%s and field2=%s" % (l1, l2))
```

Output:

```
select my_rows from my_table where field1=727 and field2=14
select my_rows from my_table where field1=454 and field2=15
select my_rows from my_table where field1=565 and field2=16
```

Related Python doc is [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

---

To create data frame with necessary fields, you can check this post: [Python Pandas Data frame creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562479/python-pandas-data-frame-creation)

---

To insert row to dataframe please check: [Insert a row to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284342/insert-a-row-to-pandas-dataframe)